# Android Room. Tracking progress of select queries

Tags: android-room, android-livedata

I use Room library to access a database. I need to select a lot of data and want to track aprogress of a loading process. Before I could track the progress when iterating over cursor. Using Room's `@Query` I can get only the whole bunch of selected data at once. Is there any possibility to track the progress of select queries using Room? Below is the query example:

```
@Query("select * from large_table")
fun getALotOfData() : LiveData<Array<OneObject>>
```

Comment: If you really have 10000+ items to show, consider returning `DataSource.Factory` from Room, and show it with a `PagedListAdapter`. But if you need to add clickable headers then that won't work for you.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'll also need to implement the list filtering and so will need to use different queries in a case of `PagedListAdapter` but thanks for the idea. Will try it.